# How do I keep some drivers from old kernel?

Tags: drivers, kernel, bluetooth

My bluetooth dongle drivers were in kernel 2.6.38. Since then it never worked with any new kernel. So my only way to use it is to boot into old kernels. But I want to update kernel to 3.1 with new drivers except Bluetooth. Can patching do this?

Comment: Sounds like a regression. File a bug report on Launchpad. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/

Answer (score 2):

open synaptic package manager, select the package you want to preserve, then from the "package" heading in the top menu check "lock version".

[image]

Comment: Thanks guys,how do I know which packages are my bluetooth drivers ?